# App Launching multi times when downloading from app store

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app on play store, which when downloaded on device causes problems. Assume I click on the launcher icon on my launcher to open the app, then I go to click the app from my drawer. The app has 2 instances launched. And if I go click from the Google store ( open) it has 3 instances launched. How can I solve this issue?

First Way I solved, but not best solution. I did my firstactivity to be launchmode="singleinstance" with no displaytheme, this firstactivity takes you to splash.So When I click on my app launcher icon, or from drawer, or from Google store it will always open firstactivity and then either take you to splash screen if app is not open or to the screen your already in if app is open.

Second way I solved, was to have in my application tag launchmode="singletop", this worked when testing to open the app between launcher and drawer. But it didn't work when I clicked open the app from play store, when I clicked open from play store it opened my app once... and after I click on my launcher it opens my app 2 instances.

First solution

> ```
>   <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity
>         android:name=".FirstActivity"
>        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
>         android:launchMode="singleInstance"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>      <activity
>         android:name=".SplashActivity" >
> ```

Inside firstactivity on create

> ```
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//open splash activity}
> ```

Second solution

> ```
>  <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:launchMode="singleTop"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity
>         android:name=".SplashActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> ```

Comment: Could you explain why singleInstance is not the best solution for you?

Comment: to answer you both. singleinstance not best solution, because at start am opening one activity with no display theme. thus opening the app slow couple of milliseconds slower. For the other question, i have seen this bug in so many apps.There are some apps i open 2 - 3 instances of at times. If you want a total code check woodworking tools https://github.com/IanGClifton/auid2 . When You upload on store and click open from google play store it will launch one instance of app, then when i click the app from launcher it will launch second instance.